# JavaScript TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null php

Tags: javascript, php

I want to execute a query in a text editor , by choosing the database in a select options.

identifier.php is the page which i have all the the conditions foreach option selected: if($database=="data1"){}

This's my code :

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label>Editor : </label>
    <textarea id = "editor" name = "editor" class="form-control" rows="10" placeholder="Enter ..."></textarea>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
 <div class="form-group">
  <select name="database" id="database" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">

     <option value="data1">data1</option>
     <option value="data2">data2</option>
     <option value="data3">data3</option>

 </select>
 </div>
 </div>

  <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="executor();">Execute</button>


   <h3 id = "results">Results</h3>
   <script>
       var editor = editor.edit("editor");
   </script>

   <script>
      function executor() 
        {
          document.getElementById('cover').style.display = "block";
          contentsql = editor.getValue() ;
          dbvalue = document.getElementById("database").value;
          $.post( "identifier.php", { query: contentsql , database: dbvalue  })
          .done(function( data ) {
          document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = data ;
          $('#cover').fadeOut(500);
         });
        }

        </script>
```

Code of the page Idnetifier.php :

```
  require_once ('../../config/connection.php');
  function array2table($array, $recursive = false, $null = '&nbsp;')
   {

     if (empty($array) || !is_array($array)) { return false;}
    if (!isset($array[0]) || !is_array($array[0])) { $array = array($array);}

    $table = " <div id='' class='pull-right'>
    <form action='/module/getCSV.php' method='post'>
        <input type='hidden' name='csv_text' id='csv_text'> 
        <input type='submit' value='Export as CSV' onclick='getCSVData()' class='btn btn-success btn-xs'>
    </form> 
</div>
<table class='table datatable' id='table_without_sorting'  >\n";

// The header
$table .= "\t<tr>";
// Take the keys from the first row as the headings
foreach (array_keys($array[0]) as $heading) {
    $table .= '<th>' . $heading . '</th>';
}
$table .= "</tr>\n";

// The body
foreach ($array as $row) {
    $table .= "\t<tr>" ;
    foreach ($row as $cell) {
        $table .= '<td>';
      $kounter++;
        // Cast objects
        if (is_object($cell)) { $cell = (array) $cell; }

        if ($recursive === true && is_array($cell) && !empty($cell)) {// Recursive mode $table .= "\n" . array2table($cell, true, true) . "\n";
        } else { $table .= (strlen($cell) > 0) ?htmlspecialchars((string) $cell) :$null;}

         $table .= '</td>';
       }

             $table .= "</tr>\n";
         }

      $table .= '</table>';
          return $table;
      }

   $query = $_POST['query'];
   $database = $_POST['database']; 
   $sql = $query ;

   if($database=="data1"){
       $request = $co_data1 -> prepare($sql);
       $request -> execute();
       $data_request = $request -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    if($database=="data2"){
      $request = $co_data2 -> prepare($sql);
      $request -> execute();
      $data_rreq = $request -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
       }    

    if($database=="data3"){
       $request = $co_data3 -> prepare($sql);
         $request -> execute();
        $data_request = $request -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
       }    




         echo   array2table($data_request);

        echo "<hr>";
        echo "<b>".$kounter."Database: ".$datbase."</b>";

        ?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the identifier.php file too? I think we have to help you there.

Comment: @M4R1KU I added the code of identifier.php.

Comment: can you say what's your actual problem. Maybe show an error or something like this or say where you stuck.

Comment: the button is not working and there's more there this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'edit' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

So, you have muliple problems.

I assume your submit/executor button is in a form tag which has an action attribute. In this case after you have clicked the button the form will be submitted and the javascript function (executor) has no chance to be fully executed because you are making a redirect.

If this is true you have to prevent the default action of the form this work like this.

```
function executor(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
}
```

and the button:

```
<btn... onclick="executor(event)" ...>...</btn>
```

And what's your aim with the editor.edit("editor")? Is that from a library?
editor is clearly undefined because you don't have a editor variable until this point.

Comment: what I want is to write a query in the editor choosing database using the select option after clicking the button normally it should execute the request .
My code not work and it not show me any error

Comment: when i modify y code to preventdefault, this's the error  : JavaScript TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null